# MySQL: Alternative to ORDER BY something LIMIT 0,1

Tags: mysql

Is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column=something ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,1;
```

**EDIT**:I have a table with columbs: `ID Name Date`.  I want to get the most recent entry (using the date column) where Name is Bob.

Comment: Abstract questions will only get vague answers.

Comment: What's wrong with this query?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I have an idea of writing small .net application that formats any sql query accodring to the rules you've thinked of/invented (to get a practice in lexers/parsers). What do you think of this? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Urge to kill... *rising*... :p

Comment: @OMG Ponies: so do you think the idea is terrible? ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With no more information, we can't tell. You *could* most likely use MIN/MAX in a subquery, but there's no way to tell if it would be better or not.

I'm thinking about something like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE column = something
AND date = (SELECT MIN(date)
            FROM mytable);
```

P.S. I'm not a fan of SELECT *, it's usually more readable if you type the column you are selecting.

Comment: @Vincent Savard: It is not either better or worse - it is another query. Your query does not guarantee to return only one row.

Comment: That's basically what I'm saying.

Comment: @Vincent Savard: i don't see it ;-) anyway, your query will be slower, if the OP's criteria of better/worse is performance.

Comment: @zerkms: Yep, you're right, it will be slower. It's just an alternative.

Comment: @Vincent Savard: any reason to have alternative **slower** and **more difficult to read** query? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Say that to pedrofurla, he's the one that asked the question!

Comment: @Vincent Savard: hehe, ok ;-)

Comment: @Vincent Savard: I didn't ask the question, @sixtyfootersdude did! :P

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column=something GROUP BY field1,field2,date,...,fieldn HAVING date>=(select date from mytable);
```